# Prestashop 1.7.2 + Nginx 1.10 + SSL - Rewrite Rules

Tags: ssl, nginx, prestashop, ubuntu-16.04

I keep getting 404 error when trying to navigate to the frontend shop of a Prestashop 1.7.2 site products page.I am having some problems with images not shown. However it is fine when going to the admin backend.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

This is my /etc/nginx/site-available/default conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/h2o.prod.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/h2o.prod.error.log;

        root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 165.227.162.248;
        #Specify a charset
        charset utf-8;
        # Gzip Settings, convert all types.
            gzip on;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied any;

            # Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
            # gzip_comp_level    5;
            # gzip_min_length    256;

            gzip_types
                application/atom+xml
                application/javascript
                application/json
                application/ld+json
                application/manifest+json
                application/rss+xml
                application/vnd.geo+json
                application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                application/x-font-ttf
                application/x-web-app-manifest+json
                application/xhtml+xml
                application/xml
                font/opentype
                image/bmp
                image/svg+xml
                image/x-icon
                text/cache-manifest
                text/css
                text/plain
                text/vcard
                text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
                text/vtt
                text/x-component
                text/x-cross-domain-policy;
                # Supposed to be the case but we never know
                # text/html;

        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

        location ~* \.(eot|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|otf|pdf|png|svg|swf|ttf|woff)$ {
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg break;
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 break;
    # next line is PSCSX-2790 bug workaround, fixed in 1.6.0.10
    rewrite ^/[a-zA-Z]+/img/cms/(.*)$ /img/cms/$1 break;
    expires 1M;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    allow all;
        }

        # Block everything else in these directories
        location ~ ^/img/cms/ {
                deny all;
        }

        # 1 week expiry on CSS and JavaScript
        location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
                expires 1w;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
                allow all;
        }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/medicalstrechers17/admin1900/index.php/(.*) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /medicalstrechers17/admin1900/index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;


    }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                    expires max;
                    log_not_found off;
        }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you haven't the correct file permissions, try this by ssh with root:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/medicalstrechers17/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/medicalstrechers17/
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you post NGINX configuration, I advise to hide the admin directory URL. Then, I can think of two things. Are you using multilanguage? If so, add the following lines to your config. For example, english and spanish:

```
rewrite ^/es$ /es/ redirect;
rewrite ^/es/(.*) /$1;
rewrite ^/en$ /en/ redirect;
rewrite ^/en/(.*) /$1;
```

Then, if that does not work, add this (single language):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Or this (multiple languages, in this case spanish and english):

```
location ~ (/es|/en)/index\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Let's see if it helps!